# Codeignighter page data not displaying

Tags: php, codeigniter

I trying to get a very simple query results set to display on a page using Codeignighter.

For my controller i have this:

```
class Homepage extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('string');
    $this->load->helper('text');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('Job_sectors_model');
}


public function index(){
    $page_data['sectors'] = $this->Job_sectors_model->get_sectors();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('homepage', $page_data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
}
```

and for my model file i have this:

```
    class Job_sectors_model extends CI_Model {

      function get_sectors() {
        return $this->db->get('sectors');
      }

    }
```

On my view file i have a simple select:

```
                  <select class="form-control" name="job_sectors">
                     <option>Choose job sector...</option>
                     <?php foreach ($sectors->result() as $row) : ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row->nc_id ; ?>"><?php echo $row->tc_name ; ?></option>
                     <?php endforeach ; ?>
                 </select>
```

I have this setting in my autoload.php file:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

The page loads and the select has the correct number of items from the db table. What I am getting is an error in each of the seelcts option when you open the select. I see thiswhen I inspect it:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$nc_id
Filename: views/homepage.php
Line Number: 68
```

So the nc_id is a table column name, its just not returning the value. How do i define the property to stop this error from happening?

Many thanks
M

---

Ok i now have it working but it doesnt feel right:

so my model is this:

```
    class Job_sectors_model extends CI_Model {

    function get_sectors() {

        $query = $this->db->get('sectors');
        return $query->result_array();

    }        

    }
```

my view is this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="job_sector">
                <?php foreach ($sectors as $sector): ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $sector['NC_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $sector['TC_NAME']; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </select>
```

and my controller is this:

```
class Homepage extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('string');
    $this->load->helper('text');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('Job_sectors_model');
}


public function index(){
    $this->load->view('header');
    $page_data['sectors'] = $this->Job_sectors_model->get_sectors();
    $this->load->view('homepage', $page_data);
    $this->load->view('footer');    
}
```

When I say ity doesnt feel right is this the right way to code in codeigniter, feels like i'm hacking it together to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities. 1 the column name actually doesn't exist, 2 you don't have any rows.
This prevents the later from causing issues.

```
class Job_sectors_model extends CI_Model {

      function get_sectors() {
        $q = $this->db->get('sectors');
        if ($q->num_rows > 0) {
            return $q->result();
        }
        return false;
      }

    }
```

View:

```
        <?php if ($sectors): ?>
          <select class="form-control" name="job_sectors">
                 <option>Choose job sector...</option>
                 <?php foreach ($sectors as $row) : ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row->nc_id ; ?>"><?php echo $row->tc_name ; ?></option>
                 <?php endforeach ; ?>
             </select>
          <?php else: ?>
             No sectors
          <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Columns do exist and data is present. I have 2 rows of data at the moment for testing.

Comment: in view `print_r($sectors)` what is it?

Comment: It returns: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [NC_ID] => 1 [TC_NAME] => DRIVING [DC_DATE_CREATED] => 2018-08-09 [TC_CREATED_BY] => Matthew ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [NC_ID] => 2 [TC_NAME] => COMMERCIAL [DC_DATE_CREATED] => 2018-08-09 [TC_CREATED_BY] => Matthew ) )

Comment: did you try `$row->NC_ID` instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass the data from the model in $pagedata and pass it while loading the view it will generate the array like this

```
$this->load->view('homepage',['pagedata' => $pagedata] ) ;
```

on view you can use directly if single row $pagedata->nc_id
else you can simply use foreach loop like this

```
<?php foreach ($pagedata as $row) {?>
//your code inside and access db rows by $row->nc_id
<?php } ?>

//don't use colon after foreach loop its php
```

Comment: there is no difference between `array('somekey' => $someresults)` and `$data['somekey'] = $someresults`. he is passing it to the view correctly; also `<?php endforeach ; ?>` is valid syntax

Comment: okok i understood but he can try an either way or else the row is missing

Comment: The <?php endforeach ; ?> is alternative php syntax. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/alternative_php.html

Answer (score 0):

why are you sending db->get object to view instead result object/array ? is there any specific reason ???

instead the normal method should be like

```
class Job_sectors_model extends CI_Model {

      function get_sectors() {
        $result =array();
        foreach($this->db->get('sectors')->result() as $row)
         {
           $result[$row->nc_id]=$row->tc_name ;
         }
        return $result;

      }

    }
```

and instead of :

```
<select class="form-control" name="job_sectors">
                     <option>Choose job sector...</option>
                     <?php foreach ($sectors->result() as $row) : ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row->nc_id ; ?>"><?php echo $row->tc_name ; ?></option>
                     <?php endforeach ; ?>
                 </select>
```

view file should be like :

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('job_sectors', $sectors, 'default_value',' class="form-control" ' ); ?>
```

after putting `$this->load->helper('form');` in your controllers constructor